# How i can test a useeffect cycle ? and see and a table

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

my cycle in the useEffect, i call an api and i look if in the search?q= value, has a value if not y call all the results in the api

```
const [val, setval] = React.useState([]);
const varo = new URLSearchParams(props.props.location.search).get('search');

React.useEffect(() => {
  if(varo!=null){
    talent.searchList(varo)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data, "data ");
        setval(data.message.data.data);
        return val
      });
   } else {
     talent.searchList('')
       .then(({ data }) => {
         console.log(data, "data ");
         setval(data.message.data.data);
         return val
       });

   }
  
}, [varo]);
```

Comment: please inject code into post rather screen-shot it

Comment: sorry I thought put the code

Comment: `
  React.useEffect(() => {
   if(varo!=null){
    talent.searchList(varo)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data, "data ");
      setval(data.message.data.data);
      return val
    });
   }else{
    talent.searchList('')
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data, "data ");
      setval(data.message.data.data);
      return val
    });

   }
  
  }, [varo]);
  `

Comment: how `val` is used in render?

Comment: in a ant desing <Table datasource={val}/>